# Why TFS ServiceHooks delayed?

Tags: tfs

Why TFS ServiceHooks delayed in a few hours before it works.
In the history of the ServiceHooks it shows at Summary, sent at 11:13 while the response was at 09:13

Comment: Which web hook are you using? Could you add more related info? Did the delay always be 2 hours？

Comment: Web API on IIS . the delay  was 2 hours now it is 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the web hooks sent time from history (reference below screenshot),

[image]

Take a look at the time setting(eg: China Standard time here) to check it’s the real delay but not **due to Time zone difference.**

If the delay happens consistently and each time delay hours, highly doubt it's a time zone difference, not a real delay. Please double check your server time zone and web site's.

Comment: it is not only  differences in  time, it also delayed the action taken by the web service.